# How to apply successive methods on object

Tags: python, oop

I have defined an object that will have an argument. Then I have created 3 methods as:

1. `do_it1` will add 10 on value of the object
2. `do_it2` will add 20 on value of the object
3. `do_it3` could accept an argument then it should add 30 plus its input argument on what's applied on.i.e. to what is on the left side.

Here's what I did

```
class MyClass():

def __init__(self,object_value):
    self.object_value = object_value

def do_it1 (self):
    return self.object_value + 10

def do_it2 (self):
    return self.object_value + 20

def do_it3 (self,input_number):
    self.input_number = input_number
    return  + 30 + self.input_number
```

here is the output

```
MyClass(5).do_it1()
```

returns 15 which is correct

```
MyClass(4).do_it2()
```

returns 24 which is correct

```
MyClass(4).do_it2().do_it3(6)
```

returns AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'do_it3'
while I was expecting 60 as 4 + 20 + 30 + 6

```
MyClass(1).do_it1().do_it2().do_it3(9)
```

returns AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'do_it2'
while I was expecting 1 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 9 = 70

How I could apply a method on top of method(s) in same class

Comment: You're returning the result of an operation on one of the class's members, in this case an int. Hence why you cant call the class method on it (its just an int). Return the class itself in the methods and you should be able to chain the calls. When you're done you can access the result by accessing `MyClass.object_value`

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you tried walking through the code on paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `self` (or a copy of it, via `import copy`, `copy.copy(self)` or similar) for this to work.
The accrued value has to be accessed via the `object_value` property.

In code:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,object_value):
        self.object_value = object_value

    def do_it1(self):
        self.object_value += 10
        return self

    def do_it2(self):
        self.object_value += 20
        return self

    def do_it3(self, input_number):
        self.input_number = input_number
        self.object_value += 30 + self.input_number
        return self


MyClass(4).do_it2().do_it3(6).object_value
# 60
MyClass(1).do_it1().do_it2().do_it3(9).object_value
# 70
```

(method `do_it3()` may or may not do what you want, your code is invalid so I just guessed, but it is not too relevant)

Comment: Or at least an object of some kind.

Comment: @IgorRivin `int` is an object of some kind, yet it does not work because `do_it*()` methods will not be defined. But you are right that for more complex class hierarchies one can return something different, as long as the required methods are defined.

Comment: A lot of the time, when this pattern is used, a clone/copy is returned by the "chainable" methods instead of `self`. Then you can have references to objects where the functions have and haven't been applied

Comment: @norok2, could you explain the meaning of adding `.object_value` at the end to make it works.

Comment: @Maged That is to access the property by that name from the object.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement you call **init** which creates an object of MyClass self.object_value = 5 and then you call do_it1() of it

```
MyClass(5).do_it1()
```

In the second one you do the same thing, but you create an object with self.object_value = 4 and then you call.do_it2()

```
MyClass(4).do_it2()
```

In the last one it returns you an error because you create the object MyClass with self.object_value = 4, then you call do_it2() which returns an Int value, so you will have Int.do_it3(6) in the end, which raises an error because the int object has no method do_it(3). All of the return value of MyClass(4).do_it2() is an int and then you call a method that is not a method of the return object.

```
MyClass(4).do_it2().do_it3(6)
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you did not understand.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could explain why it works with this setup:
`MyClass(1).do_it1().do_it2().do_it3(9).object_value` 
Why adding `object_value` at the end resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

As these methods return `int`s, you can only call int methods on their results.

Your invocation `MyClass(4).do_it2().do_it3(6)` is equivalent to `24.do_it3(6)`, which does not make much sense.

Comment: To be precise, is equivalent to `(24).do_it3(6)` as you need the extra parentheses to access the methods of numerical constants.

Answer (score 0):

For MyClass(4).do_it2().do_it3(6) the problem is that do_it2() returns an integer; to that integer you are applying the method do_it3(), but the integer class does not have any method call do_it3(). You could try:

```
MyClass(4).do_it3(6 + MyClass(4).do_it2())
```